# Issue with ClosedReceiveChannelException and Data Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing a piece of code which uses Kotlin's coroutines pipilens and Androids Data Binding.

While working i've found that when my couroutine crashes due to the 'ClosedReceiveChannelException' the bound View Model (through Data Binding) doesn't update the 'Data Bound components'.

```
fun onProcessStart(cachedImageId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    text = "Started for image: $cachedImageId"

    try {
        val extractedTextPipe = extractText(cachedImageId)
        val processedTextPipe = processText(extractedTextPipe)
        val processedText = processedTextPipe.receive()
        text = "Finished for image: $cachedImageId"
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        Log.d("TEST", t.message+ " "+t)
        text = "Failed for image: $cachedImageId with code: ${t.message}"
    }
}
```

Altough the catch is triggered and the `Log.d` is present in the logs the `text` with the new message is never updated.

That wouldn't be a suprise if the following didn't work as well:

```
 fun onProcessStart(cachedImageId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        text = "Started for image: $cachedImageId"

        try {
            throw IllegalStateException()
            text = "Finished for image: $cachedImageId"
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("TEST", t.message+ " "+t)
            text = "Failed for image: $cachedImageId with code: ${t.message}"
        }
    }
```

The above code works - the text from the `catch` is updated.

My question is - why once the `val processedText = processedTextPipe.receive()` throws `ClosedReceiveChannelException` the `text` value stops from being updated.

-- edit
This issue can be also observed with the following:

```
  text = "Started for image: $cachedImageId"

    try {
        delay(10000)
        throw IllegalStateException()
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        Log.d("TEST", t.message + " " + t + " " + Thread.currentThread().id)
        text = "Failed for image: $cachedImageId with code: ${t.message}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well - after a good night's sleep I've figured out that I have forgotten to use `LiveData` in the `text` field.